# Why is valid_date? for now is true, but for tomorrow is false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Doing some validation for dates I found that valid_date? is giving me a false value if the date is in the future (date after current date) but all other dates is true.

Example:

These return true:

```
valid_date? DateTime.strptime(DateTime.yesterday.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%d-%Y")

valid_date? DateTime.strptime(DateTime.now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%d-%Y")
```

But this returns false

```
valid_date? DateTime.strptime(DateTime.tomorrow.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common use for `valid_date?` is to attach dates that are occuring or occured to models.
Therefore future dates aren't valid because it didn't happen yet!

[Edit]

#### For validating future dates:

If you are using `DateTime` to construct your dates it will aways give you a valid `DateTime`.

To parse a date a user entered use either `DateTime.strptime` or `DateTime.parse`, you can even set the format using the former.
If the parse fails (invalid `DateTime`) it will give you `nil`.

Something good about `ActiveRecord`, if your model knows the field should be a `DateTime`, the presence validator should be enough as it will try to parse the string for you.

Comment: Did know that, thanks! Know any way of doing this validation with future dates included?

Comment: Well, if you are using DateTime.something directly it will aways give you a valid date.
If you are parsing an user entered date (string), it will be `nil` when it fails to parse (which means it's invalid).

That is, if your model knows the field should be a Date, the presence validator should be enough.

Comment: @FutoRicky, Added future-date-parsing-and-validation explanation to the answer.